# ContextNotActiveException when using RestClient

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-oidc

I'm currently using quarkus to develop a microservice based application. I need to modify the SecurityIdentity (the user is authenticated with oidc) to inject a list of permissions retrieved from another microservice. I'm currently using this for the purpose:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RolesAugmentor implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    CoreServiceClient coreServiceClient;

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext context) {
        return context.runBlocking(build(identity));
    }

    private Supplier<SecurityIdentity> build(SecurityIdentity identity) {
        if (identity.isAnonymous()) {
            return () -> identity;
        } else {
            QuarkusSecurityIdentity.Builder builder = QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder(identity);
            var permissions = coreServiceClient.getPermissions();
            builder.addRoles(new HashSet<>(permissions));
            return builder::build;
        }
    }

}
```

where CoreServiceClient is a RestEasy RestClient used to retrieve the user permissions, but when I run the code I get a javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException

Any idea on how to accomplish this task?

Thanks
euks

Comment: Are you using the `quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation` extension?

Comment: No. How can I configure the extension in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I'm using context propagation now and it seems to work. Here's the updated code.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RolesAugmentor implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    CoreServiceClient coreServiceClient;

    @Inject
    ThreadContext threadContext;

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext context) {
        return context.runBlocking(build(identity));
    }

    private Supplier<SecurityIdentity> build(SecurityIdentity identity) {
        return threadContext.contextualSupplier(() -> {
            if (identity.isAnonymous()) {
                return identity;
            } else {
                JsonWebToken jwt = (JsonWebToken) identity.getPrincipal();
                QuarkusSecurityIdentity.Builder builder = QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder(identity);
                var permissions = coreServiceClient.getPermissions("Bearer " + jwt.getRawToken());
                builder.addRoles(new HashSet<>(permissions));
                return builder.build();
            }
        });
    }

}
```